# Convert java.math.BigDecimal to scala.math.BigDecimal?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to convert a java.math.BigDecimal to a scala.math.BigDecimal, and I can't find a method to do it.

I've tried to convert a List[BigDecimal] in the following way,

```
payments.map(_.asInstanceOf[math.BigDecimal])
```

which gives the error

```
java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to scala.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: That's not a conversion; that's a cast.

Comment: Sorry then... How do I cast a java.math.BigDecimal to scala.math.BigDecimal?

Comment: You should have taken a look at the doc first, the answer lies right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the factory.

```
payments.map(scala.math.BigDecimal(_))
```